# explain output in js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am getting an issue in the below code:

```js
let a = 13;

function printA() {
  let a = 19;
  console.log(this.a);
}
let obj = {
  a: 10,
  fun: function() {
    console.log(this.a);
  }
};
let obj2 = {
  a: 20
};
let x = obj.fun;
x();
```

can anybody tell why it is printing undefined ?
It prints 13 when we remove let from let a = 13

Comment: `let a = 13` makes a local variable. `a = 13` (in non-strict mode) creates a global variable, which is actually a property on the global object (`window.a` or `global.a`). `x()` calls `x` as a function (i.e. without changing `this`, so `this` will remain the global object), Thus, `this.a` is again accessing property `a` on the global object. The global variable is not a local variable, so you get `undefined`.

Comment: if we change let with var in above code and run it on google console than its shows the correct output but undefined in vsCode

Comment: `var` is deprecated in favour of the newer `let` and `const` because it has surprising properties; one of them being that it makes local variables except at top scope, when it makes global variables. I know nothing of vsCode, but if it executes files with node, then it is not in the global scope, while in a browser it is.

Comment: can you suggest references for learning JavaScript?
Thankyou!

Comment: @AshishKumar The series by Kyle Simpson (Getify) are the best for learning and comprehending JS.

Comment: @AshishKumar for JS tutorials talking about this, check this [article](https://medium.com/@amesimmons/i-dont-know-js-a59b578284fb) and [You-Dont-Know-JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) and yet the best of  all tutorials for javascript  [understand-javascript](https://www.udemy.com/course/understand-javascript/) the first 3 hours of this Udemy tutorial is all about how javascript works.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `a` for your `x` to fetch, that is why you get `undefined`.

```
let obj = {
    a: 10,
    fun: function () {
        console.log(this.a);
    }
};

let x = obj.fun;
x();
```

Your `x` is pointing to a `function` as `obj.fun`. But there is no `obj.fun.x` exist, so it will result `undefined`.

Try the following:

```
let obj = {
    a: 10,
    fun: function () {
        console.log(this.a);
    }
};

let x = obj;
x.fun();
```

or

```
let obj = {
    fun: function () {
        this.a = 10;
        console.log(this.a);
    }
};

let x = obj.fun;
x();
```

They both will result `10` as output.

These two example both have an x property under the `x`.

> NOTE: By making a `let a = 10` under the `fun` function will not give you result of `this.a` is because such declaration works like a `private` parameter declaration in C/JAVA etc.